# Form won't reset after alert (when validated)

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I validate my form with jquery validate and everything goes fine. What won't work is that, after successfully validating I want it to send an alert and clear the form. The alert will pop but the form won't reset. I can make it reset if I don't have the alert, but both won't work at the same time:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 var validator = $("#contacto").validate({
    errorLabelContainer: "#messageBox",
    wrapper: "li",
    submitHandler: function() { alert("Formulario enviado") }
 })
 validator.resetForm();

 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            $(document).ready(function() {
         var validator = $("#contacto").validate({
            errorLabelContainer: "#messageBox",
            wrapper: "li",
            submitHandler: function() { alert("Formulario enviado");
 validator.resetForm();
    $("#contacto")[0].reset(); 
         }
         })

         });
```

your reset call was outside. so it will be only call once after page load.

Comment: I did that and still won't reset.

Comment: call $("#contacto")[0].reset();

Comment: Yes! thank you :D Do I even need validator.resetForm();
 at all?

Comment: you should also try with sergzach suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Why not:

```
submitHandler: function( form ) { alert("Formulario enviado"); $(form).reset();
 }
```

?